# iPhone - How can you get a URL from the Second UIViewController to Load in a WebView in the first UIViewController

Tags: iphone, url, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

What im trying to do is I have a Bookmarking System in place but my problem is to get the URL from the UITableView in the Second UIViewController and the load the selected URL to Load in to the WebView in the First UIViewController is it possible. I do have some code in place but thats not working to i need a solution to my problem

heres the code I currently have in place

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    NSString *urlWeb = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [controller.igiWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlWeb]]];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

ViewController *controller = [[ViewController alloc]init];

NSString *urlWeb = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[controller.igiWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlWeb]]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is initializing another instance of your previous view controller instead of using the existing instance loaded into the navigation stack. So, when you call the dismissViewController method, your view is dismissed and you have neither used the newly created instance nor the existing instance.
I would suggest to make a delegate and use that to pass the selected URL back to the FirstViewController.
In FirstViewController.h, use the following code outside the `@interface` block of class FirstViewController.

```
@protocol UserSelectionDelegate
-(void)userSelected:(NSString*)selectedURLString;
@end
```

Inside the SecondViewController's `@interface` block,

```
id<UserSelectionDelegate> delegate; //Make a property of this as well
```

and in SecondViewController's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method use:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSString *urlWeb = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self.delegate userSelected:urlWeb];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Now all you have to do is go back to the FirstViewController.m and at the point where you create the SecondViewController's instance add `secondVCInstace.delegate = self;` and then implement the `userSelected:` method to load the URL into the FirstViewController's webView.