# Getting data from popped view controller to parent view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem where I am able to pass all data to a push view controller using

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Expense" sender: self];
```

and

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

However I do not know how to get back data when the view controller is popped out. I have a couple of arrays that need to be passed from a popped view controller to parent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to serve as the data model for your application and have it include the arrays you need to pass around.  Create an object of that class in your first controller, share it with the second controller during `prepareForSegue:`, let the second controller update it, and read the new values when the parent's view appears again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use segues to pass data forward and Delegate Methods to send data back in your navigation stack. That is the recommended approach. I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674271/iphone-how-can-you-get-a-url-from-the-second-uiviewcontroller-to-load-in-a-web/13901694#13901694) earlier. Although the question may sound different, the underlying solution should work in your case as well.

Comment: As u provided link i tried its giving back error as "can not find protocol declaration for UserSelectionDelegate " how to solv this . thank you for the reply

Comment: That's because you probably haven't declared the UserSelectionDelegate. You have to declare that protocol before being able to use it. Declare it in the First View Controller that you want the data to get passed back to.

Comment: As i am new to iOS can you please provide couple of line of code how to declare it.